# Why doesn't ${*// /*} work to replace blanks with * in command line arguments?

Tags: bash, replace

I want my script to perform the product of all its integer arguments. Instead of performing a loop I tried to replace blanks with `*` and then compute the operation. But I got the following result which I don't understand:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# product.sh

echo $(( ${*// /*} ))  # syntax error with ./product.sh 2 3 4
args=$*
echo $(( ${args// /*} ))  # ./product.sh 2 3 4 => outputs 24
```

How is it that the first one produces an error while using an intermediate variable works fine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*How is it that the first one produces an error*:
From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> *If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied **to each positional parameter** in turn*

(emphasis mine)
That is, the expression `${*// /*}` replaces spaces **inside** positional parameters, not the spaces separating positional parameters. That expression expands to `2 3 4` (which gives a syntax error when used in an arithmetic context), since the parameters itself don't contain a space. Try with

```
./product '2 ' '3 ' 4
```

and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 6):

You may utilize `IFS`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# product.sh

# set IFS to *
IFS='*'

# use IFS in output
echo "$*"

# perform arithmetic
echo "$(( $* ))";
```

**Output:**

```
2*3*4
24
```

Comment: No `$(( ${args// /*} ))` is not a nested curly bracket expression. Arithmetic context `$(...))` is applied after resolving inner bracket expression

Comment: _"Reason why echo $(( ${*// /*} )) doesn't work because bash doesn't allow nested expressions."_ -- no, it's not.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Try: `s='123#aaa.bbb'; echo "${#${s%.*}}"`

Comment: @anubhava, yes, so? Bash doesn't support nested parameter expansions like that, but that's not the reason the original didn't work: the original didn't _have_ a nested parameter expansion. It had a parameter expansion within an arithmetic expansion, which actually works. Try e.g. `foo=x; echo $(( 3 ${foo/x/*} 5 ))`. The problem was that the expansion in the question didn't produce that asterisk, which is explained in the other answers, and which you can verify by printing the result of that expansion alone, without the arithmetic.

Comment: I have already commented `$(( ${args// /*} )) is not a nested curly bracket expression` yesterday

Comment: `local` outside a function is illegal.

Comment: Thanks, since I was testing using a function I just copy pasted from there, fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

In your example, the value `$*` does not actually contain any literal spaces, so `${*// /*}` does not do anything.

If it did, those asterisks would be subject to wildcard expansion, so the idea of performing a substitution would seem to be rather brittle even if it worked.

I would simply create a function to process the arguments, instead of rely on trickery with substitutions -- these tend to have icky corner cases when one of the arguments is a variable or etc.

```
mul () {
    case $# in
      [01]) echo "$@";;
      *) local n=$1; shift; echo $((n * $(mul "$@")));;
    esac
}
```

Comment: An expanded value with `*` inserted _used directly in a command_ is at risk from wildcard (formally pathname expansion), but not in arithmetic `$(( ))`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You're right, that consideration can be ignored in the OP's example ... but would still be tricky to pick apart and debug in isolation, for instance.

Comment: a recursive function? How very Lisp. Wouldn't just `mul() { s=1; for a in "$@"; do s=$((s*a)); done; echo "$s"; }` do and be possibly easier to read?

Comment: @ilkkachu Sure it would; matter of taste. Don't forget to make your variables `local` though.

Answer (score 5):

Or use `printf`, like this:

```
echo $(( $(printf '%s*' $*)1 ))
```

Comment: Or with an parameter expansion, `echo $((1${*/#/*}))`